# query to find the count of each member in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine there is a table with these columns

```
Table 1 : id
          Name
          Family
```

We want to find the count of each member in the column .
I wrote the query with CTE but I want to know if there are better solutions
in the picture below you can see the query and the result.
[image]

Comment: What edition of sql server do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use COUNT() with OVER :

```
declare @vt_source as table
( id int not null,
  name varchar(50) not null)

 insert into @vt_source(id,name)
 values (1,'pantea')
 ,(1,'pantea')
 ,(2,'shidea')

 select distinct
    id
    ,name
    ,count(*)over(partition by id 
                       order by name asc 
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as idCount
    ,count(*)over(partition by name 
                       order by id asc 
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as nameCount
 from
   @vt_Source
```

output:

```
id  name    idCount nameCount
1   pantea  2       2
2   shidea  1       1
```

**EDIT:**
as @Lennart sugested, the `count` part can be rewritten like this:

```
,count(*)over(partition by id) as idCount
,count(*)over(partition by name) as nameCount
```

Comment: Try to change the second row like this: (3,'pantea')

Comment: @sepupic, ok - I've done the change; it is adding a row with `3,pantea` and is this the desired output?

Comment: Your query will produce 2 rows for pantea: every row will report name_count = 2. in my opinion it should be id_count=1 and name_count=1 for (1, pantea) and for (3, pantea)

Comment: In the initial query, for the name is doing a count for the name ,not keeping the id. here is the initial query http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e622fb174b2486737df256a771ca856

Comment: No, I'm sorry, you are right. I misunderstood the question

Comment: You can shorten your window like: ` count(*) over (partition by id) as idCount` . Strictly speaking the default window without an order is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, but that won't matter.